# Hölder's inequality: What does $\|\cdot\|_1$ refer to when it's an integral?

Tags: notation, definition, holder-inequality

Hölder's inequality: What does $\|\cdot\|_1$ refer to when it's an integral?

In the L.H.S. of Hölder's inequality.

Comment: $\|f\|_1 = \int_\Omega |f| \, dx$.

Answer (score 3):

$$||f||_1 = \int_a^b |f(t)|dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in L^{1}[0,1]$. Then, $||f||_{1} = \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| dt$.